# Unable to view or change file permissions

Tags: permissions, directory

I tried to view file permissions

```
$ ll yaan/
ls: cannot access yaan/.: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/Nenje Nenje - TamilTunes.com.mp3: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/Aathangara Orathil - TamilTunes.com.mp3: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/Hey Lamba Lamba - TamilTunes.com.mp3: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/list: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/Latcham Calorie - TamilTunes.com.mp3: Permission denied
ls: cannot access yaan/Nee Vandhu Ponadhu - TamilTunes.com.mp3: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ./
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ../
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Aathangara Orathil - TamilTunes.com.mp3
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Hey Lamba Lamba - TamilTunes.com.mp3
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Latcham Calorie - TamilTunes.com.mp3
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Nee Vandhu Ponadhu - TamilTunes.com.mp3
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Nenje Nenje - TamilTunes.com.mp3
valar@valar-Desktop:/song$ cd yaan/
bash: cd: yaan/: Permission denied
valar@valar-Desktop:/song$
```

Also I have tried to change file permission, but it doesn't throw error.

```
$ sudo chmod 644 yaan/
$
```

Also, I am not able to open the files. How do I recover them? Or change file permission and ownership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Because `yaan` is a **directory** ,you have to give the execute  permission like that:

```
sudo chmod 744 yaan
```

---

### Explanation:

7 => give the **read**, **write**, and **execute** to the **Owner**.

4 => give the **read** to the **Group**.

4 => give the **read** to the **Others**.

---

From the [chmod manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) page

> execute/search  only  if  the
>          file  is  a **directory** or already has execute permission for some user

Answer (score 0):

Change permission on this way:

```
sudo chmod 644 yaan
```

w/o trailig slash. If you want to change it recursively use

```
sudo chmod -R +r yaan
```

just add read permission to world